# Storing from std::vector to std::set where vector contains a structure but std::set contains only one element from the struct

Tags: c++, vector, set

How do I copy all elements of a vector which is a struct of elements, to a set.

```
    struct info
    {
      std::string code;
      std::string curDate;
      int         iVar;

    };

    std::vector<info> infVect; // Load data into the vector from the database

    std::set<std::string> uniqueCodes;


  for ( int i = 0; i < infVect.size() ; ++i)
      uniqueCodes.insert(infVect[i].code);
```

Is there a faster way to store the elements from vector to set without iterating each element in the loop?

Note:

`std::set<std::string> uniqueCodes(infVect.begin(), infVect.end() )`, would work if `infVect` had only code. But `infVect` is a vector of objects.

Comment: No, there isn't a faster way than visiting each element. Check out [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine. A `for` loop is the simplest way to express what you mean in this situation. A C++11 range-based `for` is even simpler:

```
for (const auto& i : infVect)
  uniqueCodes.insert(i.code);
```

If you want an alternative for the sake of having one, here’s how to do it by only gluing together STL features.

Run it through [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to extract the member and insert it into the `set`. The `mem_fn` helper turns a member function or member variable into a functor.

```
std::transform(
  infVect.begin(),
  infVect.end(),
  std::inserter(uniqueCodes, uniqueCodes.end()),
  std::mem_fn(&info::code)
);
```

If `code` were private, you’d need a getter to give to `mem_fn`.

```
const std::string& getCode() const { return code; }
```

You need the following headers.

```
#include <algorithm>  // transform
#include <functional> // mem_fn
#include <iterator>   // inserter
```

If you don’t care about preserving the original `vector`, you can use [`std::move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) in C++11 to move strings without reallocation, and avoid the `<functional>` dependency for `mem_fn` by using a lambda.

```
using namespace std; // for brevity
transform(
  make_move_iterator(begin(infVect)),
  make_move_iterator(end(infVect)),
  inserter(uniqueCodes, end(uniqueCodes)),
  [](info&& x) { return move(x.code); }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to visit every node, but you can hide the iteration away in `std::transform`

```
struct StringFromInfo { std::string operator()(const Info& info) { return info.code; } };

std::transform(infVect.begin(), infVect.end(), std::back_inserter(uniqueCodes), StringFromInfo());
```

Comment: `back_inserter` won’t work on `set` because it has no `push_back`. You need `inserter`. I wish they had fixed that in C++11.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Appreciate it.